# Добавление данных по определенным индексам в dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Имеется DataFrame, в котором один столбец состоит из `NaN`. Пример:

```
0   UAA 280 NaN  
2   UAA 280 NaN  
5   UAA 919 NaN  
7   UAA 919 NaN  
11  UAA 919 NaN  
16  UAA 919 NaN  
17  UAA 371 NaN
```

Есть список индексов строк, в которые в последний столбец надо добавить определенное число< например, это число 2.0 и список индексов [2, 11, 17]. Надо, чтобы на выходе было нечто такое:

```
0   UAA 280 NaN  
2   UAA 280 2.0  
5   UAA 919 NaN  
7   UAA 919 NaN  
11  UAA 919 2.0  
16  UAA 919 NaN  
17  UAA 371 2.0
```

Большое спасибо за все ответы!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого используется "accessor" [DataFrame.loc[]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
In [33]: df.loc[[2, 11, 17], 'C'] = 2.0

In [34]: df
Out[34]:
      A    B    C
0   UAA  280  NaN
2   UAA  280  2.0
5   UAA  919  NaN
7   UAA  919  NaN
11  UAA  919  2.0
16  UAA  919  NaN
17  UAA  371  2.0
```